# Create object array from same structure

Tags: javascript

I have the following object array that maintains the same structure:

```
var fieldObjects = [{
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Submit',
  RealFieldName: 'SubmitField',
  Name: 'SubmitField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Hours Up',
  RealFieldName: 'HoursUpField',
  Name: 'HoursUpField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Personal Hours',
  RealFieldName: 'PersonalHoursField',
  Name: 'PersonalHoursField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Hours Down',
  RealFieldName: 'HoursDownField',
  Name: 'HoursDownField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}]
```

I would like to represent this in a more readable manner. All properties should remain the same except DisplayName, RealFieldName, and Name. How can I recreate this array without declaring the entire structure for each object?

Comment: I think `map()` will work. What is the expected output?

Comment: represent it where? In an HTML+CSS document?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @TKoL I would like to recreate this variable without showing properties that have the same values for each object.

Comment: So you want each object, but with only DisplayName, RealFieldName, and Name properties?

Comment: If that's the case, read mickls solution and my comment on it.

Comment: @TKoL I would like each object with the values shown above. I would like to create a template the objects use, declare only the properties that are different, and then create an array out of the 4 objects.

Comment: I think you're going to want to create a new question because you're actually apparently asking a lot of things at once. You're asking about how you can create a 'template' object, how you can use that with other objects to fill in default values, potentially how you can extract a 'template object' from an array of similar objects, etc.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear based on what you've said if the solution is supposed to rely on DisplayName, RealFieldName, and Name properties being the ones that are different, and everything else being part of a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator:

```
let result = fieldObjects.map(({DisplayName, RealFieldName, Name, ...rest}) => rest);
```

```js
var fieldObjects = [{
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Submit',
  RealFieldName: 'SubmitField',
  Name: 'SubmitField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Hours Up',
  RealFieldName: 'HoursUpField',
  Name: 'HoursUpField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Personal Hours',
  RealFieldName: 'PersonalHoursField',
  Name: 'PersonalHoursField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}, {
  AllowGridEditing: 'FALSE',
  DisplayName: 'Hours Down',
  RealFieldName: 'HoursDownField',
  Name: 'HoursDownField',
  FieldType: 'Text',
  Type: 'Text',
  Filterable: 'FALSE',
  Sortable: 'FALSE',
  ReadOnly: 'TRUE',
}]

let result = fieldObjects.map(({DisplayName, RealFieldName, Name, ...rest}) => rest);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: based on what he's said in the comments, I feel your answer would be what he's looking for if you just changed this bit: `let result = fieldObjects.map(({DisplayName, RealFieldName, Name, ...rest}) => {DisplayName,RealFieldName,Name});`. Those are the fields he seems to want to keep

Comment: @TKoL not sure either "without showing properties that have the same values for each object. " means those should be skipped but either way spread would be the way to go